# is there any restriction on variable name so that it should not conflict with package name?

Tags: java, variable-names, package-name

Suppose, I have one Test class in test package:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    private static int clarying=20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clarying.Product.display(clarying); // this line is giving error 
                                            // The primitive type int of
                                            // clarying does not have a field Product
    }
}
```

Suppose, I have another class Product in clarying package:

```
package clarying;

public class Product {
    private static int test;

        public static void display(int data) {
            test = data;
            System.out.println(test);
        }
}
```

I have compiled the Product class and now I am trying to compile the Test class but it is throwing a compiler error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
 Unresolved compilation problem:  
 The primitive type int of clarying does not have a field Product
  at test.Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

*issue is in line:*

```
clarying.Product.display(clarying);
```

**Because the variable name is clarying  in Test class, is the same as the package name clarying**. So, when I am writing **clarying.Product** it is searching for a field **Product** inside of the **clarying** class-variable.

I just want to clarify: Is there any rule against defining a variable with the same name as a package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the complete rules here: [6.4.2. Obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that such a declaration is obscured.

Comment: thanks for the link, i got whatever i was searching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a rule. The compiler thinks you mean the field `clarying`. It has no way of knowing that you actually mean the package and I don't think there is a way to tell it that you mean the package (which would have to be something like `this` but meaning the package root instead of the current instance). Since the field is just an `int` you'll get the error that you have.

If you want to circumvent that just import the `Product` class:

```
package test;

import clarying.Product;

public class Test{
    private static int clarying=20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product.display(clarying);
    }
}
```

However, you should probably reconsider the name of your variables, since this can cause quite a bit of confusion, especially when others are trying to read your code.

Comment: solution i knew. but simply i thought because one bug has been fixed http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4240480